# How to account for empty cells when using cell references to direct VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in a table, where I compare two columns `J` and `T`. The values which `J` and `T` can take include `A2B`, `APL`, `BGF`, `CMA`, among others (see code).

If these values are equal, copy row `i` into the sheet which has the name of the cells just checked.

If these values are not equal, copy row `i` into the sheets which have the name of the cells just checked.

**Example**: Compare `J2` and `T2`,

Suppose `J2`=`T2`=`BGF` then copy row `2` and paste into `sheet("BGF")`

Next, compare `J3` and `T3`

Suppose `J3`=`BGF` and `T3`=`CMA`, copy row `3` and paste into `sheet(BGF)` and `sheet(CMA)`

Continue for `J4` etc...

**Problem**: When running this code, If `J3`=`BGF` and `T3`= nothing  (its empty), then the code throws out an error.

Similarly, if all cells have values, the program throws out a run time error at the end of the data set rather than stopping the program.

Here's my code

```
Sub Sortdata()
'step 1 clear all data
Sheets("A2B").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("APL").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("BGF").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("CMA").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("K Line").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("MacAndrews").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Maersk").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("OOCL").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("OPDR").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Samskip").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Unifeeder").Cells.ClearContents

Dim i As Long
With Worksheets("All Data")
    For i = 2 To 10000
        If .Range("J" & i) = .Range("T" & i) Then 'if two cells are equal
            .Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets(.Range("J" & i).Value).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats ' paste the value at the end of the row.
        Else
            .Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets(.Range("J" & i).Value).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats ' paste the value at the end of the row.
            .Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets(.Range("T" & i).Value).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is when you strike an empty cell, you try to reference a worksheet as

```
Worksheets("")
```

which of course fails.  So you need to avoid those references.

Here's how I would do it

```
Sub Sortdata()
    'step 1 clear all data
    Sheets("A2B").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("APL").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("BGF").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("CMA").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("K Line").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("MacAndrews").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("Maersk").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("OOCL").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("OPDR").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("Samskip").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("Unifeeder").Cells.ClearContents

    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long


    With Worksheets("All Data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If IsEmpty(.Range("J" & i)) Then
                Set ws1 = Nothing
            Else
                Set ws1 = Worksheets(.Range("J" & i).Value)
            End If
            If IsEmpty(.Range("T" & i)) Then
                Set ws2 = Nothing
            Else
                Set ws2 = Worksheets(.Range("T" & i).Value)
            End If

            If ws1 Is Nothing Then
                If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
                    CopyToWs ws2, .Rows(i)
                End If
            ElseIf ws2 Is Nothing Then
                If Not ws1 Is Nothing Then
                    CopyToWs ws1, .Rows(i)
                End If
            Else
                CopyToWs ws1, Rows(i)
                If ws1.Name <> ws2.Name Then
                    CopyToWs ws2, .Rows(i)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Sub CopyToWs(ws As Worksheet, rng As Range)
    rng.Copy
    ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very close, My button is on a different page, if I have the All data page open when I run the subprocedure, then it works perfectly. If however, I click my button on the home page, it tries to copy rows from the home page (there is no data here)

Comment: @Joshua Oops. I missed one `.` (in the final `Else`clause).  Fixed now

Comment: @chris_neilsen When both cells have the same value, the code does not copy the line at all. when it chould copy it to the sheet with the cell's value. say "BGF!"

Comment: It does for me.  Maybe there's something about your data you haven't shown us